# Get csv output from Snowflake using Python

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using the following code to get data from a Snowflake table in AWS using Python.

```
 cur = con.cursor()
 sql = "select COUNTRY_CD from COUNTRY_LIST;"
 result = cur.execute(sql)
 result_list = result.fetchall()
 print(result_list)
```

Output: [('US',), ('UK',), ('CA',)]

How do I change my Python code to instead get data like the following which I can write to an S3 file

Expected Output:
'US'
'UK'
'CA'

Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried unload option to extract the data?

Answer (score 0):

Extract each element from its tuple when getting it from the return value of `result.fetchall()`:

```
cur = con.cursor()
sql = "select COUNTRY_CD from COUNTRY_LIST;"
result = cur.execute(sql)
result_list = [code[0] for code in result.fetchall()]
print(result_list)
```